# Firebase Authenticator Error when trying to sign in to HomePage

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // text editing controllers
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  // sign user in method
  void signUserIn() async{
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text,
      password: passwordController.text,
      );
  }
```

This is my code which invokes Firebase Authenticator, but when i'm trying to sign in, I cannot log in to my HomePage and it shows me the following errors:

```
 FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1125:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:332:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:583:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _LoginPageState.signUserIn (package:startertemplate/pages/login_page.dart:42:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
#0      FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:1125:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:332:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:583:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _LoginPageState.signUserIn (package:startertemplate/pages/login_page.dart:42:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite the code & manage the error cases. Maybe something wrong with credentials, So it helps you to understand the issue:

```
void signUserIn() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text,
      password: passwordController.text,
    );
    // You can navigate to the HomePage or perform actions if sign-in was successful
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle the error
    if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
      // Firebase Authentication error
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        // Handle user not found error
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        // Handle wrong password error
      } else {
        // Handle other Firebase Authentication errors
      }
    } else {
      // Handle non-Firebase Authentication errors
      print('An unexpected error occurred: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

You can get the reference to manage the error cases from the link: [Auth Error](http://web.archive.org/web/20210818113318/https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword)

Comment: This is what i'm getting when making the changes.                                                                      
 The value of the local variable 'UserCredential' isn't used. Try removing the variable or using it.

Comment: @user22440324 I update the code, Please check now.

Comment: The code shows no errors but I can just sign in and out without writing the username and password

Comment: And now it's back to the sign in button not working